# Como eu faço para gerar aleatoriamente um nome ao clickar no botão?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+TC:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="./script/gerador.js"></script>
    <title>Lista da Semana</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Lista da Semana</h2>



    <div class="container">
      
      
    <button class="but1" onclick="gerar_nomes()">Gerar Local</button>

    </div><!--container-->  

    
</body>
</html>



function gerar_nomes(){

    var nomes = [
        'Daniel', 
        'Gabriel', 
        'Thiago', 
        'Leozinho', 
        'Pedro', 
        'Fernando', 
        'Marco', 
        'Gleica', 
        'Yudi', 
        'Wesley', 
        'Renan'
    ];
    var gerador ='#';

}

alert(gerar_nomes);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Opa, eu fiz esse exemplo no `reactJS` como demonstração, mas você pode pegar a mesma ideia de como resolver seu problema, com o `Math` você pode está gerando esse número aleatório pegando o índice de cada `array` e trazendo o seu valor. Espero que ajude, qualquer dúvida só falar. Abraços

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [nome] = useState([
    "Daniel",
    "Gabriel",
    "Thiago",
    "Leozinho",
    "Pedro",
    "Fernando",
    "Marco",
    "Gleica",
    "Yudi",
    "Wesley",
    "Renan"
  ]);
  
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState("");

  function gerar_nomes() {
    let countNome = nome.length;

    let nomeRandom = randomName(countNome);

    setNewName(nome[nomeRandom]);
  }

  function randomName(countName) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * countName);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{newName}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => gerar_nomes()}>
        Gerar Nome
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada item do array pode ser acessado via `nomes[0]`, `nomes[1]`, `nomes[2]` (...). Então, se você quer escolher um deles, você pode usar `nomes[um_numero_aleatorio]`.

A única coisa que tem que assegurar é que o `um_numero_aleatorio` está dentro dos limites do array (no caso: `nomes.lenght - 1`).

---

```js
window.document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(_) {
  const nomes = ["Daniel", "Gabriel", "Thiago", "Leozinho", "Pedro", "Fernando", "Marco", "Gleica", "Yudi", "Wesley", "Renan"];
  const index_maximo = nomes.length - 1;        // = 10
  const index_aleatorio = random(index_maximo); // = Numero de 0 até 10

  alert(nomes[index_aleatorio]);
})

function random(v) {
  var r = new Uint8Array(1); // PS: Suporta no máximo 256 items.
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(r);
  if (r[0] <= v) {
    return r[0];
  }
  return random(v); // PS: Pode causar loop infito se todos os numeros gerados forem maiores que v. É possível aumentar a probabilidade removendo os bits baseado no número máximo (ex. se o limite é 10 cabe em apenas 4bits, limitando de 0 até 16).
}
```

```html
<button>Gerar</button>
```

---

O exemplo acima faz uso do [`crypto.getRandomValues`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues), ao invés do `math.Random`.